# Accessing my app from outside the cluster?

Tags: spring, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

Hi I'm learning Helm and Kubernetes. I'm stuck, I can't access my app from outside the cluster.
I'm using minikube v1.32.0 wit docker's drivers.

I tried to use LoadBalancers, NodePorts, Tunnels, Services. Every time i get 404 or connection time out.

This is my app's chart:

```
# Source: app-chart/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: release-name-app-chart
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: app-chart-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
automountServiceAccountToken: true
---
# Source: app-chart/templates/service.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: false
  selector:
    app: helmapp
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 8080
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

My deployment:

```
# Source: app-chart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-app-chart
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: app-chart-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
      app: helmapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: app-chart-0.1.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app: helmapp
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: release-name-app-chart
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - image: "myrepo/helm-app:latest"
          name: app-chart
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {}
```

My ingress:

```
# Source: app-chart/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: release-name-app-chart
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: app-chart-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: spring
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

My app It's a simple SpringBoot project with an endpoint that returns code 200.

```
    @GetMapping("/health")
    public ResponseEntity<String> healthCheck() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was about my image. It was pulling an old version of my image so building and pushing a new one solved my problem.
The tunnel started changing docker password.

```
$ minikube ssh

docker@minikube:~$ sudo su -

root@minikube:~# passwd docker
New password:    # <-- you can set any password
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully

root@minikube:~# logout

docker@minikube:~$ logout

$ minikube tunnel
Starting tunnel for service balanced.
docker@127.0.0.1's password:  # <-- this should accept above password
```

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11580#issuecomment-1337288420

Comment: You should add a content that fully explains the solution instead of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Minikube requires the use of `minikube tunnel` to issue an IP that allows you to access the service from outside the cluster.

Once you have that running in a separate terminal window, you should find an IP assigned to your service, and when that happens you can use `localhost:{port}/{path}` to access your service

---

I took your yaml and created this in order to test if the setup was correct (I swapped out your image for the basic `tomcat` to check if its your image or config. Tomcat still runs on 8080)

```yaml
# Source: app-chart/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: release-name-app-chart
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: app-chart-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
automountServiceAccountToken: true
---
# Source: app-chart/templates/service.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: false
  selector:
    app: helmapp
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 8080
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
---
# Source: app-chart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-app-chart
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: app-chart-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
      app: helmapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: app-chart-0.1.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-chart
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app: helmapp
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: release-name-app-chart
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - image: "tomcat:latest"
          name: app-chart
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {}
```

This gives me a pod like this:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
release-name-app-chart-64c7c5d558-4j4rd   1/1     Running   0          94s
```

And also a service:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
app-service   LoadBalancer   10.105.50.32   127.0.0.1     8080/TCP   5m17s
kubernetes    ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP    7m33s
```

The "EXTERNAL-IP" field value of 127.0.0.1 for app-service will only appear if `minikube tunnel` successfully started up

If we `kubectl log` the new pod we can see some details:

```
$ kubectl logs -f release-name-app-chart-64c7c5d558-4j4rd
...
08-Mar-2024 18:00:29.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
08-Mar-2024 18:00:29.960 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Mar-2024 18:00:29.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [289] milliseconds
```

Now, if we (from the host machine) try to curl localhost on port 8080, that should go through the tunnel and access the service if everything is setup right

```
$ curl localhost:8080
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/10.1.19</h3></body></html>
```

Okay, so we get a 404, but look at the last bit:

`<h3>Apache Tomcat/10.1.19</h3>`

And compare that with the log message:

`08-Mar-2024 18:00:29.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]`

This confirms your config is right and you've mapped everything correctly.

The 404 you're getting would imply your server is not handling the requests right.

Finally,

> My ingress:
>
> ```
> # Source: app-chart/templates/tests/test-connection.yaml
>  .....
> ```

This is not an ingress. What you have inside this file is a Helm test hook (https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_test/)

An ingress is something completely different and you can read about that here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: When i run the tunnel i get asked for a password, but everything i write i got the tunnel started. Don't know what is going on.. Anyway even with tunnel i can't access my cluster.

Comment: If you run `kubectl config get-contexts` do you get the `minikube` cluster with a `*` under the `CURRENT` column?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11580#issuecomment-1337288420

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much, now i can start my tunnel, but still getting 404.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some debugging

Comment: I'm Sorry, I corrected the question with the right template, thank you for the correction!